# Debugging Formatting functions in SAP UI5

Tags: sapui5

In my application i have Included a formatter.js file in a seperate folder of sap ui5 application and declared this file in controller of the view

```
<Page title="{i18n>MasterTitle}" >
    <List
    id="list"
    type="Active"
    items="{/SalesOrderCollection}" >
    <ObjectListItem
        type="Active"
        title="{SoId}">
        <attributes>
            <ObjectAttribute text="{ path: 'OrderedDate', formatter: 'com.corp.demo.sales.util.Formatter.date' }" /> 
        </attributes>
       <firstStatus> 
              <ObjectStatus text="{OverallStatus}" /> 
       </firstStatus>
    </ObjectListItem>
</List>
</Page>
```

but could not able to format the date it is showing as blank.  iam able to log in to  formatter.js file using console.log statements but the date function is not getting triggered

How can i check the whether the date function is getting triggered ?

Thanks,
Prasad

Comment: Are you sure you need quotes in line `<ObjectAttribute text="{ path: 'OrderedDate', formatter: 'com.corp.demo.sales.util.Formatter.date' }" />` ?

Comment: Yes they are needed.

Comment: I mean double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use debug mode in web ide.
You can use this path.

```
project settings-run configurations-web application-url components
```

Add the `sap-ui-debug=true` parameter to your URL.

Comment: iam not using web-ide .using Eclipse for the project.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex" in index.html.